# Adding a String into an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

```
String [] Letters = {
    "a", ...... , "z",
};    

new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(Letters));
```

Am currently using the above code, which I believe it creates an ArrayList from the Array call Letters(Please correct me if I'm wrong). I need to know how to add a new String into the ArrayList. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(letters));
// Java naming convention - variables start with lower case ^^
list.add("some new string");
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm just wondering, wouldn't the system be wasting memories on creating an extra list of array from letters[]? from what I know, new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(Letters)); actually convert letter[] into and arrayList right? or am I wrong on that?

Comment: No, it initializes a new arraylist with the content of the array.

Comment: if ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(Letters)); is initiating a new arraylist what does List<String> list = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(letters)); do? it seems to me that it's initiating it again.

Comment: the same, only assigning the arraylist to a variable, so you can refer to it later, you can use `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(letters));`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `List.add` method

```
List myList = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(Letters));
myList.add(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about,

```
String [] Letters = {
    "a", ...... , "z",
};    

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(Letters));
arrayList.add("My String");
```

?